# accounts-ui with meteor cluster

Tags: meteor

I am having 2 applications 'service[server-app]' and 'website[client-app]' connected with meteor cluster and I connected 'service' application with mongodb. I am using accounts-ui for login and signup through 'website' application. Below provided is my code and is this the right way to do so

website application

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {  
        var usr = ddpconn.call('CreateUser', user); // ddp cluster connection to the service app
        return usr;
 });
```

service application

```
Meteor.methods({
  CreateUser: function (user) {
    var invited = Invitations.findOne({"user_id":user._id});
    if(invited){ 

            // Updates the subdoc of invited user
            Meteor.users.update({"_id": invited.user_id,"rules._id":usr.rules[0]._id},{ $inc:
                {"rules.$.lineup": 1} });

            Invitations.update({"user_id":invited.user_id},{$set:{"updated_at":new Date()}});

            // Adds a rules subdoc to the user which creates an account
            user.rules = [ { "_id" : new Mongo.ObjectID()._str, "lineup" :1} ]
            return user;
        }
    } else {

        // Adds a rules subdoc to the user which creates an account
        user.rules = [ { "_id" : new Mongo.ObjectID()._str, "lineup" : 1} ]
       return user;
    }
  }
});
```